# Simultaneous local and remote connectivity in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Can you run a command on local and remote systems at the same time in PowerShell? I know that you can run a command to multiple remote systems using PowerShell but is there a command or a way you can run the same command to local and remote machines at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Not at the same time, but yes in the same command. For example, if I wanted to grab the computer info of my local machine and then off a remote machine named CoolComputer2 in one command, I would do the following:

```
Get-ComputerInfo -and (Invoke-Command -ComputerName CoolComputer2 -Credential domain\username -ScriptBlock { Get-ComputerInfo})
```

The first `Get-ComputerInfo` grabs local info.

The `-and` says "if this first command works, do this next command second.

`Invoke-Command` allows you to execute a remote command, entering the computername and the credentials to access it after it.

`ScriptBlock` needs to have the remote command inside of curly braces `{command here}.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell remoting can be used against any computer that is properly configured to allow it. This includes "localhost", which is always the local computer.